# How do i take in non-space separated inputs C++

Tags: c++

I want to count the number of '#' in a grid. This works if the imput is space separated but it doesn't if its not. How do I make the first one work?

```
 3 3    3 3
.##    . # #
#.#    # . #
###    # # #
Fails  Works
```

```cpp
using namespace std;
int main() {
    int h, w, i, o, total = 0;
    string current;
    cin >> h >> w;
    for (i = 0; i < h; i++) {
        for (o = 0; o < w; o++) {
            cin >> current;
            if (current == "#") {
                total += 1;
            }
        }
    }
    cout << total;
}
```

Comment: define current as char

Answer (score 2):

This is because when you give the input that is not space separated, then it takes the whole row as a single string, because **string is only terminated when you enter a space or return**. 
 Therefore, in your case you take the string as **".##"**, then you compare it with **"#"**, that returns false. That's the reason of its failure.
If you want to make it space separated then you can use this code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int h, w, i, o, total = 0;
    char current;
    cin >> h >> w;
    for (i = 0; i < h; i++) {
        for (o = 0; o < w; o++) {
            current = getch();
            cout << current;
            if (current == '#')
                total += 1;
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    cout << total;
}
```